# How to eliminate a particular value from a mysql query when it has more than one value and leave as it is when it has only one value

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query which returns more than one row for few ID's with different values. In such a case i need to eliminate the ID's with certain data

Example

```
ID   Name  Value
1     A1     AA    
1     B1     AB
2     C1     CC
3     A1     AA
4     A1     AA
4     E1     AD
4     B1     AB
```

I need to eliminate A1 for all those ID's which has more than one name and else if it has only  one value A1 then i should be able to display it.

Result Should look like

```
ID    Name    Value
1      B1      AB
2      C1      CC
3      A1      AA
4      E1      Ad ---- Any random value from the two
```

Help me with a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand the spec - but this does provide the correct result set for that particular data set...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x    
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id,MAX(name) max_name FROM my_table GROUP BY id ) y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.max_name = x.name;
```

Comment: but max(name) would filter the value there itself and give me the random result but i need to check if the id has multiple values and only if it has multiple values then i need to check if one of it is A1 and eliminate that and display one of the rest values for that ID.

Comment: Perhaps your sample dataset isn't properly representative of the problem at hand!